# Next/previous links in a view based on contextual filter in the url

Tags: views

I have a page view in a Drupal 7 view with contextual filters in the URL.  something like /events/%1/%2 - the first parameter is the year, the second is a taxonomy term. So /events/2014/3 is all the events in 2014 in category 3.

I want to provide next and previous links based on the year (the first filter parameter). Is this even possible?

Comment: Like next and previous year?

Comment: Yes, a next year and previous year. Ideally they'd be in the view header, but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your strengths are, but you could easily accomplish this with a custom php block.  If you did something along the lines of

```
<?php
$previous = arg(2) - 1;
$next = arg(2) + 1;
?>
<a href="/events/<?php print $previous . '/' . arg(3)?>/">Previous</a> 
<a href="/events/<?php print $next . '/' . arg(3)?>/">Next</a>
```

I would clean up that code and use the l() function to create a link, but that is the general concept.

Comment: Beautiful answer! Welcome to Drupal answers.